# The right way to keep docker container started when it used for periodic tasks

Tags: docker

I have docker container with installed and configured software.

There is no any programm supposed to be started/runned all the time.

What I want - its ability to start some command depending on external events. like:

```
docker exec mysupercont /path/to/mycommand -bla -for
```

and

```
docker exec mysupercont /path/to/myothercommand
```

But "exec" impossible when container is stopped, and also this container have some "working" data inside, which used for that commands, so I can't use

```
docker run ...
```

each time, because it recreate container from image and destroy my data.

What is the "right" and the "best" way to keep such container runned? 
Which command I can start inside?

Comment: This is a very well explained question. See another similar post [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29087099/docker-container-started-in-detached-mode-stopped-after-process-execution/35206183#35206183).

Comment: `docker run -d --name=name container tail -f /dev/null`

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You do not need to perform each time `docker run`.

`docker run` is actually a sequence of two commands: "create" and "start".

When you run the container, you must specify the "`-it`":

> -i, --interactive=false    Keep STDIN open even if not attached
>   -t, --tty=false            Allocate a pseudo-TTY

Example:

```
docker run -it debian:stable bash
```

After the work was completed command specified at startup (in my example bash). For example, you perform the "exit". Container stops:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                CREATED             STATUS                     PORTS               NAMES
1329c99a831b        debian:stable              "bash"                 51 seconds ago      Exited (0) 1 seconds ago                       goofy_bardeen
```

Now you can start it again

```
docker start 1329c99a831b
```

The container is started and again executes the command "bash".
Connect to this session "bash" with the command

```
docker attach 1329c99a831b
```

**To sum up**: you have to understand the difference between the `run` and `start` container.
Besides, look at the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/) for the role of parameters "`-i t`" and "`-d`" for the "Run"

Comment: aha, i understand this. Question was: I have nothing to run inside container, but i need to keep it in "run" state
So your answer is - use bash to keep container in running state?

Comment: Yes.The process that you specified at run time must be running to the container continued to work. The simplest example is bash.
Perhaps you will be the easiest way to start the container with the "-d" and connect to it as needed using the `docker attach ID`.
Get out of this session without ending bash, you can use `CTRL-p CTRL-q`

Comment: Process that you specify during of the container run receives the PID 1. Accordingly, the container simply can not work without it ☺

Comment: My experience with start and attach (or start with -ai) is that the prompt and interactive editing of your command line doesn't show. EG the tty isn't rendering or echoing.

Comment: This is nifty. Note that if you want to start the container in the background without having to manually start it again (say if you're running a web service), use '-itd' parameters, and CTRL-p CTRL-q to detach without stopping the container.

Answer (score 31):

Since you mentioned periodic tasks and you are probably using something like cron because of the way you want to use `docker exec`, I have just the medicine for you. At least I ended up doing something like this.

1. Dockerfile

   ```
   FROM <some base>
   CMD tail -f /dev/null
   ```
2. Run with the usual `docker run -d ....` (I used `docker-compose`)
3. Setup host machines crontab, for example:

   ```
   * * * * * docker exec mysupercont foo >> /var/log/foo.log 2>&1
   * * * * * docker exec mysupercont bar >> /var/log/bar.log 2>&1
   ```

I find this solution nice as we get to rely on the ancient and proven crontab in a pretty default linux environment, while Docker handles your business logic's more exotic deps and environment variables. You can also set some limits if your periodic tasks get stuck & have memory leaks or whatever.

Comment: ingenious! works great.

Comment: this is actually really clever !

Answer (score 16):

Tail will still causes some file operations from time to time.

**Sleep Forever, without any side effects**

```
# Ah, ha, ha, ha, stayin' alive...
while :; do :; done & kill -STOP $! && wait $!
```

**How it works**

```
while :;           # Run an endless loop,
do :;              # of do nothing,
done &             # as background task.
kill -STOP $!      # Stop the background task.
wait $!            # Wait forever, because background task process has been stopped.
```

Comment: hard to understand what its doing.  why not just sleep 3650d

Comment: You're right, sleep would probably work as good as my solution, however sleep will time out eventually :-D
PS: I will add some comments, to make my solution easy to understand.

Comment: how about $! is reused by others?

Comment: @user565230 what do you mean?

Comment: LOL this hack worked :p

Comment: How is this better than doing "tail -F /dev/null"

Comment: This is very helpful when using a Docker container as the development environment for say a CLI application.

Comment: IMO its better than "tail -F /dev/null" because when I go to stop the container it responds to the SIGTERM and stops immediately. While using the tail command, you may notice it seems to ignore the request to be stopped, so then Docker has to resort to using force stop it after so many seconds.

Answer (score 11):

This whole business of whether or not you can start a stopped container, is dependant on how the container was originally created, i.e. run.  If you ran a command that ended, or you exit an interactive command, e.g. bash, you can't start, restart or exec the stopped container.  All you can do is remove it.  It's junk.

But taranaki's last comment, use '-itd', seems to be what the docker ordered.

The container keeps running, and you can exec whatever you want, and you can stop, start or restart the container.  Of course, this is just a preliminary finding based on the alpine image.  Note, if you attach to the container, it will stop when you exit, but you can start it again.

Comment: +1 "seems to be what the docker ordered" :-)

Comment: Ditto :D I'm stealing this.

Comment: So if you run `docker run -itd myspercont /bin/bash`, then the docker image keeps running on the background and also react properly (and quickly) on `docker stop` - in some other solutions docker waits for timeout during stop attempt and then it is killed.

Answer (score 2):

I've used all of the proposed solutions here myself, but all of them do not handle SIGTERM signals coming from the Docker daemon when it wants to shut down the container (e.g. `docker stop $containername`).

So I propose the following:

```
FROM base:image
# ...
CMD sh -c 'trap "exit" TERM; while true; do sleep 1; done'
```

It is basically a short shell script that first intercepts ("traps") SIGTERM signals and then goes to sleep for a second in an infinite loop.

I mainly use it together with docker-compose and [ofelia](https://github.com/mcuadros/ofelia) to supply side-car containers to backup some other service in another container (e.g. MariaDB databases).